# Windows PuTTY PSCP command exclude files or folder not to be transferred to server

Tags: windows, putty, pscp

How to exclude files or folder not to be transferred to server with Windows PuTTY PSCP command?

My command:

```
pscp -r -i "D:\my-key.ppk" D:\wamp\www\abc\* ec2-user@58.55.86.157:/var/www/html
```

It transfers all files and directories. I want to exclude some directory let's say `runtime\` and its content.

I googled but no commands found.

Please help.

Comment: why don't u use `rsync` for this? It offers `include` and `exclude` flags

Comment: i am not sure pscp allows anything with skip

Comment: Where can I download rsync for windows. @Nishant Sing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows

Comment: FileZilla is one of the options for transferring files between different OSs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pscp` does not have any filters. All you can do is to explicitly list all the other files and folders for upload, skipping the `runtime`.

```
pscp -r -i "D:\my-key.ppk" D:\wamp\www\abc\file1 D:\wamp\www\abc\file2 ... ec2-user@58.55.86.157:/var/www/html
```

---

Or use another SFTP/SCP client, which supports filters (exclude masks).

For example, with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) you can use this batch file (`.bat`):

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://ec2-user@58.55.86.157/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa ..."" -privatekey=""D:\my-key.ppk""" ^
    "put D:\wamp\www\abc\* /var/www/html/ -filemask=""| runtime\""" ^
    "exit"
```

References:

- [Automating file transfers to SFTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [`put` command and its `-filemask` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put)
- [Exclude masks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#include_exclude)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*